# how does prediction markets automated market makers work with examples?

Tags: market-making, binary-options, cryptocurrency

I am trying to replicate the prices in prediction markets

For example on below manifold calculates, how does new probability and payout estimate changes on manifold

[image: Manifold example]

or on Futuur example similarly, how is if you win amount, and avg price/share calculated
[image: Futuur example]